# Ubuntu server not returning complete php file

Tags: php, ubuntu

My Ubuntu 14.04 server running on digital ocean is not returning my complete php file to the browser. I can see it in the "View Source" option in the browser.

Actually, my `index.php` file is currently placed in the `/var/www/html/` but some of the files that my php refers are in the parent directory of html, that is in, `/var/www/`. Will that be an issue?

My actual php code is:

```
<? require_once("../includes/configure.php");
  require_once(DIR_FS_SITE_CONTROL."includes/admin_configure.php");


    if($Page !="")
    {
        if(file_exists(DIR_FS_SITE_CONTROL_ADMINSCRIPT.$Page.".php"))
        {
            if(in_array($Page,$PagePermissionArray) || in_array("*",$PagePermissionArray))
                require_once(DIR_FS_SITE_CONTROL_ADMINSCRIPT.$Page.".php");                     
        }
    }

    if(@$_REQUEST['Meta'] !="false")
        require_once(DIR_FS_SITE_CONTROL_INCLUDES."control_meta.php");
    ?>
<body leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="3" marginheight="3">    
<?php 
if(@$_REQUEST['Popup'] !="true")
    require_once(DIR_FS_SITE_CONTROL_INCLUDES."control_header.php");
    ?>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="" align="center" valign="top">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="98%">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" align="center" style="padding-top:6px;">
                    <?
                        if(session_is_registered("InfoMessage") && $_SESSION['InfoMessage'] !="")
                        {
                    ?>      <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" border="0" align="center" class="InsideTable">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="middle" width="20"><img src="<?=DIR_WS_SITE_CONTROL_IMAGES?>info.png"></td>
                                    <td><font color="Red"><b><?=$_SESSION['InfoMessage']?></b></font></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <br>
                    <?      $_SESSION['InfoMessage']="";
                        }
                        elseif(session_is_registered("ErrorMessage") && $_SESSION['ErrorMessage'] !="")
                        {
                    ?>      <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" border="0" align="center" class="InsideTable">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="middle" width="20"><img src="<?=DIR_WS_SITE_CONTROL_IMAGES?>error.png"></td>
                                    <td><font color="Red"><b><?=$_SESSION['ErrorMessage']?></b></font></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <br>
                    <?      $_SESSION['ErrorMessage']="";
                        }

                    ?>
                    <!-------Start Here --------->
                    <? if($Page !="") 
                        {
                            if(file_exists(DIR_FS_SITE_CONTROL_FORMS.$Page.".php"))
                            {
                                if(in_array($Page,$PagePermissionArray) || in_array("*",$PagePermissionArray))
                                    require_once(DIR_FS_SITE_CONTROL_FORMS.$Page.".php");
                                else    
                                    echo"<b>You do not have permission to access the page.</b>";

                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                echo"<b>Page is under construction.</b>";
                            }
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            echo "&nbsp;";
                        } ?>
                        <!-------End Here--------->
                    </td>
                 </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<? 
if(@$_REQUEST['Popup'] !="true")
    require_once(DIR_FS_SITE_CONTROL_INCLUDES."control_footer.php");?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function InitCall()
    {
        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "index.php",
               data: "",
               success: function(msg){
               }
             });

        setTimeout('InitCall()', 600000);
    }
    InitCall();
    </script>
    <?
$sk_timeend = explode(' ', microtime() );
$sk_timeend = $sk_timeend[1] + $sk_timeend[0];
echo "<!--".number_format($sk_timeend-$sk_timestart,3)."-->";   
?>
</body>
</html>
<? //@mysql_close();
   ob_end_flush();
?>
```

But all I am getting from my server to my browser is:

```
<? require_once("../includes/configure.php");
  require_once(DIR_FS_SITE_CONTROL."includes/admin_configure.php");


    if($Page !="")
    {
        if(file_exists(DIR_FS_SITE_CONTROL_ADMINSCRIPT.$Page.".php"))
        {
            if(in_array($Page,$PagePermissionArray) || in_array("*",$PagePermissionArray))
                require_once(DIR_FS_SITE_CONTROL_ADMINSCRIPT.$Page.".php");                     
        }
    }

    if(@$_REQUEST['Meta'] !="false")
        require_once(DIR_FS_SITE_CONTROL_INCLUDES."control_meta.php");
    ?>
<body leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="3" marginheight="3">
```

I firstly tested with a dummy php file and it was working fine then. So I assume that there is no issue with the php or mysql configurations. I don't know what problem is with this specific php.

Also, Is there any problem when I put some `includes` in the parent directory of `html` that is inside, `/var/www/`?

Thanks.

Comment: Short opening tags `<?` are off in PHP configuration. Eiter edit the config, or (preferably) use `<?php`.

Comment: @lafor, I replaced all the short tags with `<?php`, Now I am getting nothing from the server in the page source :/

Comment: @lafor, Do I need to place all the contents inside `/var/www/html` or some files (other than index.php) be present  in the parent of html ??